# How can I change the download path of the Webdriver at runtime after initialization of the driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have initialized the driver and in my scenario I navigate to the page where I get an unique Id for the data and there are some documents related to that data which I need to download so I get this unique Id and want to set the download directory based on this id for the same driver.

I need to perform this scenario multiple times with different data but I'm not sure how to change the download path of the webdriver at runtime after my driver is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading and setting path when the driver is updating is out of scope there is a solution for this that called [Webdriver Manager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)
Try this so you don't need to download and installed chrome driver exe files